# How to find N (start number) at the determination of limit of sequence?

Tags: limits

I have this determination of limit:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} f(x)=A \quad :=> \quad \forall{\varepsilon>0} \quad  \exists{n>N}: \quad |x_n-A|<\varepsilon $$

For example I have this sequence: $ x_n=\dfrac{2n-1}{3n+4} $. Let $ 
\varepsilon=\dfrac{1}{1000} $. How can I find N ?

Comment: Well, you have to know the limit of the sequence: $A= 2/3$. After that, you have to solve the inequality $$|x_n-A| < \varepsilon$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct formulation is:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=A \quad <=> \quad \forall{\varepsilon>0} \quad\exists N \quad  \forall n>N: \quad |x_n-A|<\varepsilon$

If $x_n=\dfrac{2n-1}{3n+4}$ then we try $A=2/3$: with $\varepsilon=\dfrac{1}{1000}$ we get

$|x_n-A|<\varepsilon \iff \frac{11}{9n+12}<\dfrac{1}{1000}$.

Your turn !